# Error on new/Fresh eclipse application?

Tags: android, eclipse

Nothing fancy or anything, cant seem to find an answer on Go0gle, so what does this error mean? I'm very new to Eclipse and android programming, I have just created a new project, haven't changed a thing in any file, I just clicked debug to see if everything is in order and this is the error I got:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
The method onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab, FragmentTransaction) of type MainActivity must override a superclass method   MainActivity.java   /WFApp/src/com/example/wfapp    line 93 Java Problem
```

I have no idea what this means. I'm using eclipse/android/cordova/html5/javascript/css3.

But like I said, I haven't started coding yet. Any links or advice will be appreciated.

MainActivity.java :

```
    package com.example.wfapp;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.NavUtils;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide fragments for each of the
     * sections. We use a {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will
     * keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it may be best
     * to switch to a {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections
        // of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding tab.
        // We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have a reference to the
        // Tab.
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
            }
        });

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by the adapter.
            // Also specify this Activity object, which implements the TabListener interface, as the
            // listener for when this tab is selected.
            actionBar.addTab(
                    actionBar.newTab()
                            .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                            .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }



    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
        // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in the ViewPager.
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to one of the primary
     * sections of the app.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0: return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase();
                case 1: return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase();
                case 2: return getString(R.string.title_section3).toUpperCase();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }

    /**
     * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply displays dummy text.
     */
    public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
        public DummySectionFragment() {
        }

        public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
            textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            Bundle args = getArguments();
            textView.setText(Integer.toString(args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return textView;
        }
    }
}
```

edited to include.java file!

Comment: im new to this juned. Where would i get that file? then i'll upload it

Comment: You mean `MainActivity.java` file? it will be under your projects root directoryies `/src/your package name/` Have you added `cordova-2.1.0.jar` in java build path ?

Comment: sorry for late post, but my mainactivity.java is put in the question now!

Answer (score 2):

It's a problem with Java compiler. Compiler compliance level 1.5 doesn't allow `@Override` annotation for classes implementing interface methods. In Eclipse, go to project properties, select Java compiler and change compiler compliance level to 1.6 or 1.7.

Comment: yes that has helped to fix that error, but now i am struggeling with this gem _Description Resource Path Location Type
Archive for required library: 'assets/www/cordova-2.1.0.js' in project 'WFApp' cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file WFApp  Build path Build Path Problem_